# Strange "Fore" Words

Tags: adjectives

Ok, so these are old words in the English language, that I am sure. They are "Aforementioned", "Aforesaid", and "Aforethought". What I found out that they all have in common in a Webster's New World Dictionary is that they involve actions done "before". So, my question is, why do they have the prefix "A" in front, since it seems to hint something done "after" not "before"?

Comment: I would use "forethought", not "aforethought".  And bear in mind that the term "fore" is likely of nautical origin, which throws in lots of twists.

Comment: Etymonline has some interesting thoughts about fore and afore: https://www.etymonline.com/word/afore

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. / Obviously, if Y is after X, X is before / afore Y.

Comment: Why do you think "it seems to hint something done after"? Seems a total *non sequitur*. Can you explain? All I can think of is "there is an 'a' in the word 'after'" but I'm sure it can't be anything that dumb.

Answer (score 4):

The **a-** prefix in older words can be an intensifer. However, **afore** is a Middle English word [that has stuck around](https://www.etymonline.com/word/afore?ref=etymonline_crossreference), coming from Old English *onforan* (*on + foran,*) meaning *in front.*

The value of adjectives like *aforesaid *for lawyers across the centuries is that they can of course be used as nouns, and allow for necessary specificity in documents.

***"With reference to the aforesaid..."***

*Aforethought* is only used poetically, or in the archaic phrase describing the mental state required to be found in murder cases, which is *malice aforethought*, i.e. premeditated killing, as opposed to, say, manslaughter.